# What does passing arguments in this way mean?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm learning about javascript and I see this block of code that I don't understand:

```
exports.configure = ({
   expressapp = null,
   userdb = null,
   path = '/myroute'
} = {}) => { 
   // handle routes
};
```

I'm most confused about the structure of the argument being passed in and what is going on inside there. Where can I find more information about that so I can read about it? What is it even called when you pass arguments like that? Why would you want to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is a destructuring assignment which assigns a plain object as the default parameter, to avoid `TypeError` if no value is passed to the function.

```js
const exports = {};

exports.configure = ({
   expressapp = null,
   userdb = null,
   path = '/myroute'
}) => { 
   // handle routes
   console.log(expressapp)
};

try {
  exports.configure();
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

```js
const exports = {};

exports.configure = ({
   expressapp = null,
   userdb = null,
   path = '/myroute'
} = {}) => { 
   // handle routes
   console.log(expressapp)
};

try {
  exports.configure();
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read this page for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Basically if we assign

```
var [a,b] = [2,3];
```

it makes sense that we get a=2 and b=3. Think of it as a mirror.

And if we assign

```
var {a: x, b: y} = {a: 3, b: 4}
```

it makes sense that x=3 and y=4
(because the 'a' position on {a: x, b: y} is occupied by x and the 'a' position on {a: 3, b: 4} is occupied by 3, so it would make logical sense to assign 3 to x.)

A) This can be extended to function parameters, where we can have

```
function myFunc({a:x, b:y}){//do stuff}
```

and calling myFunc({a: 3, b: 4}) would imply x = 3, y = 4

---

B) We now ask ourselves why we need to introduce an x and y. Instead we could just have

```
function myFunc({a:a, b:b}){//do stuff}
```

and calling myFunc({a: 3, b: 4}) would imply a = 3, b = 4

---

C) What if we have missing information? Then we could do

```
function myFunc({a:a = 1, b:b = 2}){// do stuff}
```

Now calling myFunc({b:4}) would imply a = 1, b = 4. 
And calling myFunc({}) would imply a = 1, b = 2. 
 Because you can think of {} as {a: undefined, b: undefined}

---

D) What if the entire argument (the entire object) was missing? That's an entirely different thing altogether, and would cause an error. To answer that lets do a simpler example.

```
function simple(a=3){//do stuff};
```

Calling simple() would trigger the default argument, implying a=3

Going back to our more complex function, we can write

```
function myFunc({a:a = 1, b:b = 2} = {}){// do stuff}
```

Similarly, calling myFunc() would trigger the default argument, implying

```
{a:a = 1, b:b = 2} = {}
```

and you can think of that as

```
{a:a = 1, b:b = 2} = {a: undefined, b: undefined}
```

which makes 'a' undefined, and 'b' undefined, triggering the default argument, which implies a = 1, b = 2

---

E) Now we introduce a shorthand where

```
var {a:a} = {a:3}
```

is the same as

```
var {a} = {a: 3}
```

Going back to our function, we can see that

```
function myFunc({a:a = 1, b:b = 2} = {}){// do stuff}
```

is equivalent to

```
function myFunc({a = 1, b = 2} = {}){// do stuff}
```

This doesn't add any functionality, just cleans things up

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as writing

```js
exports.configure = (argument = {}) => { 
   // handle routes
};
```

where argument is

```js
{
   expressapp = null,
   userdb = null,
   path = '/myroute'
}
```