# JS/ES6: Destructuring of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using some destructuring like this:

```
const { item } = content
console.log(item)
```

But how should I handle `content === undefined` - which will throw an error?

The 'old' way would look like this:

```
const item = content && content.item
```

So, if `content` is undefined -> `item` will also be undefined.

Can I do something similar using destructuring?

Comment: See also [JS destructuring. How to deal with null or undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390089/js-destructuring-how-to-deal-with-null-or-undefined-values), [What does passing arguments in this way mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293341/what-does-passing-arguments-in-this-way-mean/)

Comment: I'd love to know why the JavaScript Gods decided this should throw rather than just treating `undefined` and `null` on the RHS like `{}`.  Wouldn't that have saved a lot of trouble?

Answer (score 392, accepted):

You can use [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation) to supply a default if `content` is a falsy value, usually `undefined` or `null` in this case.

```js
const content = undefined
const { item } = content || {}
console.log(item)                       // undefined
```

A less idiomatic ([see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433008/js-es6-destructuring-of-undefined/48433029?noredirect=1#comment91360972_48433029)) way is to spread the content into an object before destructuring it, because [`null` and `undefined` values are ignored](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md).

```js
const content = undefined
const { item } = { ...content }
console.log(item) // undefined
```

If you are destructuring function params you can supply a default (`= {}` in the example).

**Note:** The default value would only be applied if the destructured param is `undefined`, which means that destructuring `null` values will throw an error.

```js
const getItem = ({ item } = {}) => item
console.log(getItem({ item: "thing" })) // "thing"
console.log(getItem())                  // undefined

try {
  getItem(null)
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message)                // Error - Cannot destructure property `item` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
}
```

Or even set a default value for the `item` property if the input object doesn't contain the property

```js
const getItem = ({ item = "default" } = {}) => item
console.log(getItem({ item: "thing" })) // "thing"
console.log(getItem({ foo: "bar" }))    // "default"
```

Comment: "*You can also spread the content into an object before destructuring it*" - this seems both very inefficient and unidiomatic to me

Comment: @Bergi - I'll not argue about the efficiency as it depends on what you're doing with it. for loop is more efficient than forEach, but we still use the latter unless we need every ounce of performence. Why is it `unidiomatic` in your opinion?

Comment: (We use `for of` because it reads nicer and works better than `.forEach`, but they have [the same speed in today's engines](https://youtu.be/EhpmNyR2Za0?t=17m15s)). It feels unidiomatic because it just… looks weird in my eyes. `{ ...content }` is known as an idiom for "make a shallow copy of `content`", not "…or an empty object when it is undefined".

Comment: I think of it as a potential use for spread. It's less readable than short circuit, but it's another tool in the toolbox.

Comment: ```
const content = undefined
const { item } = content ?? {}
console.log(item)              
```

Answer (score 28):

```
const { item } = Object(content)
```

Comment: Can you explain this one for clarity? It does work very nicely.

Comment: @httpete it looks like it's creating a new object, and if `content` is null or undefined you just get an empty object back.

Comment: Does this work if content was a nested object?

Answer (score 15):

Destructuring the nested object is clean and short but sucks when source property is `null` or `undefined` in right side object

let say we have

```
const {
  loading,
  data: { getPosts },
} = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

**Solution 1**
if we have data **object** but no `getPosts` then we can use:
(Setting default at each level)

```
const {
  loading,
  data: { getPosts = [] } = { getPosts: [] },
} = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

**Solution 2:**
if event `data` is `undefined` then:

```
const {
  loading,
  data: { getPosts } = { getPosts: [] },
} = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint. But I lose typescript definition if data is undefined. My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755592/how-to-reduce-code-using-es6-destructuring-syntax. Can you help me?

Answer (score 11):

There is recently added: **Nullish coalescing operator (??)**.
Which basically returns right-side value, if the left-side value is null or undefined (our case with undefined instead of an object).

```
const { item } = undefined or null
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'item' of 'null' as it is  null.

const { item } = content ?? {}
console.log(item)   // undefined
```

So consider using the operator.
Also, as mentioned before in the answers, there is **|| (or)** operator.
For us, there is no significant difference in this particular case.

That's just a matter of taste, in our team, we have an agreement: we use **??** for defining default object if the target object is null or undefined, and in other cases we use **||** operator.

Answer (score 5):

I'll just add that for the OP's use case, it is also possible to use the [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
const item = content?.item
console.log(item)
```

If `content` is *null* or *undefined*, then `content.item` will not be accessed and `item` will be *undefined*.

Comment: When I read this first, I thought it would trigger the [prefer-destructuring](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) ESLint rule, but it seems like the optional chaining disarms that rule. This answer is therefore perfectly valid, although it doesn't use destructuring anymore, as intended by @user3142695.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question since the topic is "destructuring". completely ignoring the problem and doing something else is easy, but solving the actual problem is hard, because of the current language limitations

Comment: @vsync I agree that this answer doesn't 100% address the original question, but I just wanted to show a different way of approaching the problem. If you only need one variable, then unpacking might be unnecessary and not everyone might think of optional chaining. I understand that it feels a like the "don't use that, use this instead" type of answer, but it might still help someone.

Comment: Probably better as a comment than a full answer

Answer (score 5):

One can unpack undefined value, but can't unpack from undefined.
Fixing it is as easy as setting the default params value.

#### Example:

```js
(() => {
    // prepare payload
    const PAYLOAD = {
        holdingJustThis: 1
    };
    // lets unpack the payload and more
    const {
        holdingJustThis,
        itIsGoingToBeUndefined,
        itCouldThrowButWont: {
            deep
        } = {}                  // this will secure unpacking "deep"
    } = PAYLOAD;

    console.log({
        holdingJustThis
    });
    console.log({
        itIsGoingToBeUndefined  // logs {itIsGoingToBeUndefined:undefined}
    });
    console.log({
        deep                    // logs {deep:undefined}
    });
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const content = undefined
const { item } = content ?? {}
console.log(item)   // undefined
```

Comment: You should add some explanation, why `??` is in this case better then `||`.

Comment: not necessarily better, just another way of doing it.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't help if destructuring a *nested* item like `const {item: {subitem}} = content ?? {} // potential error`

Answer (score 1):

accepted answer does not work for truely undefined values which were not set by `const content = undefined`. in such cases this will work:

```
const { item } = (typeof content !== 'undefined' && content) || {}
console.log(item)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "truely undefined values"?

Comment: @Bergi I believe they're talking about un_declared_ variables vs declared variables with the value of `undefined`.  Testing the above code in a dev console where `content` is not declared or in scope will work, but replacing the assignment with `content || {}` throws a `Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined` exception.