# How to fix error while creating Tool extension from Windows Admin Center CLI

Tags: windows-server, windows-administration

This is related to developing extension for Windows Admin Center. There is SDK provided for the same by Microsoft to develop extensions. here is detail documentation which I was following "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/extend/developing-extensions"

Create tool extension:

Referring to section "Prepare your development environment" I have installed prerequisites.

After that I tried to next step to create tool by using Windows Admin Center CLI. I executed following command

*wac create --company "Contoso Inc" --tool "Manage Foo Works"*

But system gives following error

**const { readdir, stat } = require('fs').promises;
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `readdir` of 'undefined' or 'null'.**

Is there something missing while creating development environment.

**Environment details**

Windows 10 Professional,
npm@6.9.0,
node@v9.11.1,
angular cli: 6.1.5,
typescript 2.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ES6 Destructive Assignment

It will need some default value. So use like this

> const { readdir, stat } = require('fs').promises || {};

update-version.js can be edited and you could find this at 
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-admin-center-cli\src\update-version.js

Refer following link to know more about 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

This issue is same as 
[JS/ES6: Destructuring of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433008/js-es6-destructuring-of-undefined)