# Can I destructure nested variables in one line and still cope with undefined values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a variable and I want to destructure it

```js
const myFunc = ({name}) => {
  console.log(name)
}
myFunc({name: 'hey'})
```

But what if the variable is not there?

```js
const myFunc = ({name}) => {
  console.log(name)
}
myFunc({name2: 'hey'})
```

It just says `undefined`, which is fine

But what if I am destructuring more?

```js
const myFunc = ({name, structure: {type}}) => {
  console.log(name)
  console.log(type)
}
myFunc({name: 'hey', structure : {type: 'hay'}})
```

Ok, but what if the parameter is not there?

```js
const myFunc = ({name, structure: {type}}) => {
  console.log(name)
  console.log(type)
}
myFunc({name2: 'hey', structure2 : {type: 'hay'}})
```

Then it gives an (expected) error

**The question is**, how can I cope with these situations while destructuring in the same sentence? Or am I forced to destructure in 2 steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

The question is duplicated from [JS/ES6: Destructuring of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433008/js-es6-destructuring-of-undefined)

But still, this one may be of use if only looking at this particular problem

```js
const myFunc = ({name, structure: {type} = {}}) => {
  console.log(name)
  console.log(type)
}
myFunc({name2: 'hey', structure2 : {type: 'hay'}})
```