# How to reduce code using es6 destructuring syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, svelte, svelte-3, urql

I'm using [urql](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql) with [Svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte) and I'm delighted.

There is one thing I would like to improve but I don't know how.

Many times I have code like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { operationStore, query } from "@urql/svelte";
  import { EntertainmentPlayerDocument } from "generated/queries";

  const entertainmentPlayer = operationStore(EntertainmentPlayerDocument, { id });

  query(entertainmentPlayer);
</script>

{#if $entertainmentPlayer.fetching}
  Loading...
{:else if $entertainmentPlayer.error}
  {$entertainmentPlayer.error}
{:else}
  <Button disabled={
      $entertainmentPlayer.data.entertainmentPlayer.state == EntertainmentPlayerStateEnum.Finish ||
      $entertainmentPlayer.data.entertainmentPlayer.state == EntertainmentPlayerStateEnum.Making
    }
  >
    MyButton
  </Button>
{/if}
```

I use many, many and many times `$entertainmentPlayer.data.entertainmentPlayer` in my code.

Is ther a way to reduce this?

I tried this code instead:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { operationStore, query } from "@urql/svelte";
  import { EntertainmentPlayerDocument } from "generated/queries";

  const {data: {entertainmentPlayer}, fetching, error} = operationStore(EntertainmentPlayerDocument,{ id });

  // query(entertainmentPlayer); HOW TO USE THIS NOW?
</script>
```

But as you can see from the code I don't know how to call `query(entertainmentPlayer)` now.

If I use the below code I lose the typescript definitions on `entertainmentPlayer`:

```js
const entertainmentPlayerStore = operationStore(EntertainmentPlayerDocument, { id });

query(entertainmentPlayerStore);

$: ({
  data: { entertainmentPlayer } = { entertainmentPlayer: {} },
  fetching,
  error
} = $entertainmentPlayerStore);

// Here `entertainmentPlayer` is no more typed.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Just use two different variables for the operation and the result data?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: "*I lose the typescript definitions on entertainmentPlayer*" - you shouldn't. Of course, you *did* default it to `{}` - is that the issue?

Comment: Yes this is the issue. Can you help me? `data` can be `undefined`.

Comment: I don't see why TypeScript would "*lose the definitions*" then, instead of just inferring the type to be either `undefined` or the object.

Comment: Yeah, if I use that code my VSCode lose definitions on `entertainmentPlayer`. It doesn't recognize any field like `entertainmentPlayer.name` anymore. If I remove the `{ entertainmentPlayer: {} }` part the definitions are working again.

Comment: So what type does it infer?

Comment: I don't know, this is my question.

Comment: It seems to infer `{}` only.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you from just introducing extra variables in your code:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { operationStore, query } from "@urql/svelte";
  import { EntertainmentPlayerDocument } from "generated/queries";

  const queryOperation = operationStore(EntertainmentPlayerDocument, { id });

  query(entertainmentPlayer);

  const { entertainmentPlayer } = queryOperation.data ?? {};
</script>

{#if $queryOperation.fetching}
  Loading...
{:else if $queryOperation.error}
  {$queryOperation.error}
{:else}
  <Button disabled={
      $entertainmentPlayer.state == EntertainmentPlayerStateEnum.Finish ||
      $entertainmentPlayer.state == EntertainmentPlayerStateEnum.Making
    }
  >
    MyButton
  </Button>
{/if}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't used svelte myself so far

Comment: I updated the question.